# addEventListener "click" is not responding in ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, onclick, ejs

header.ejs
[image: header.ejs]

footer.ejs
[image: footer.ejs]

delicacies.ejs
[image: delicacies.ejs]

cart.js
[image: cart.js]

I am trying to make the element("span.cartcount") display as it is set to display: none in the CSS file. It should be displayed when I click on addtocart button (a.addtocartbutton).

I will also be glad if I can get directions or an alternative way of going about shopping cart system with express.js

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your code, not pictures of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` returns just the first element matching the selector. You have a `foreach()` loop that creates multiple items, you need to add the event listener to all of them. So you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and loop over them.

```
let addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll("a.addtocartbutton");
let cartCount = document.querySelector("span.cartcount");

addToCartButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    cartCount.style.display = "inline";
}));
```

Comment: Barmar, thank you so much. This is the correct answer. It worked for me. I used "span.cartcount" instead of "a.cartcount". I have been on this for some time now. I now get the gist, one has to loop through all the "addtocartbuttons". Using "document.querySelectorAll" is also key. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Barmar I tested your answer in my app. I want to handle routing with **"express"**. If I use ```event.preventDefault()``` in ```a``` tags on navigation, the routing process does not work. How do you handle that problem?

Comment: @hamid-davodi If you're using the link for navigation, it doesn't make sense to change the style in the current page because it's going away. So this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: @Barmar No, the actual goal is to transfer for example "active" class to the new page with the help of  ```addEventListener("click")```.

Comment: Each page is indendent and gets its own DOM and JavaScript context. You can't set variables, classes, etc. that transfer over to the next page. You need to use cookies, `localStorage`, session variables, query parameters, etc. for persistent state.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your comment. But to be sure, according to what you said, something like [this code](https://codepen.io/pkstyle/pen/MWYZXXe) is not possible in a real app that links are working for **real pages**, unless we use for example ```localStorage``` or ... ?

Comment: That works because the anchor has `href="#home"`. This is an ID on the same page, so there's it doesn't get reloaded. I was talking about anchors that contain a URL.